# Inserting select options into database

Tags: php, mysql

This is my php code to connect to the server  and insert each option value of each select tag into a table in the database

```
<?php 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "projectuser";
$password ="";
$dbname = "surveyproject";

//establish connection
$connection = mysqli_connect($servername , $username , $password       ,$dbname);

//check for connection errors
if ($connection->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $connection->connect_error);
}
echo "connected succesfully";

//inserting answers into db
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
# code...
for($i=1; $i<3; $i++){
   if(isset($_POST['select'])){
     $select = $_POST['select']; 
     $query = "INSERT INTO surveyanswers (answer) VALUES     ('$select')";
     mysqli_query($connection,$query);
}
}

echo "<script>alert('succesfully submitted answers , thank you')</script>";

mysqli_close($connection);
}
?>
```

this is my html code with three select tags i want the values select within in option of each select tag to be updated into the table  in the database

```
<select class="form-control" name="select">
  <option value="Very Good">Very Good</option>
  <option value="Good">Good</option>
  <option value="Average">Average</option>
  <option value="Poor">Poor</option>
  <option value="Very Poor">Very Poor</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" name="select">
  <option value="Very Good">Very Good</option>
  <option value="Good">Good</option>
  <option value="Average">Average</option>
  <option value="Poor">Poor</option>
  <option value="Very Poor">Very Poor</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" name="select">
  <option value="Very Good">Very Good</option>
  <option value="Good">Good</option>
  <option value="Average">Average</option>
  <option value="Poor">Poor</option>
  <option value="Very Poor">Very Poor</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do `var_dump ($_POST);` at the top of your php code and look at the output and you'll see the problem with your code. You need to name each select something different.

Answer (score 1):

Make the `select`s arrays.

```
<select class="form-control" name="select[]">
  <option value="Very Good">Very Good</option>
  <option value="Good">Good</option>
  <option value="Average">Average</option>
  <option value="Poor">Poor</option>
  <option value="Very Poor">Very Poor</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" name="select[]">
 <option value="Very Good">Very Good</option>
  <option value="Good">Good</option>
  <option value="Average">Average</option>
  <option value="Poor">Poor</option>
  <option value="Very Poor">Very Poor</option>
</select>
<select class="form-control" name="select[]">
  <option value="Very Good">Very Good</option>
  <option value="Good">Good</option>
  <option value="Average">Average</option>
  <option value="Poor">Poor</option>
  <option value="Very Poor">Very Poor</option>
  </select>
```

Then you can loop through the array. As is only the last `select` is sent because they all have the same name.

After that fix your SQL injection issue by using prepared statements with parameterized query. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Then your PHP could be:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO surveyanswers (answer) VALUES (?)";
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection,$query)) {
     foreach($_POST['select'] as $selectvalue){
          mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $selectvalue);
          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
     }
} else {
     printf("Error: %s.\n", mysqli_stmt_error($stmt));
}
```

Comment: i got these errors please :  mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt  and mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt

Comment: Then the prepare failed, check why. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.error.php

Comment: fixed it , thanks. but my table is still not been updated. i used the              $select= $_POST;  and var_dump($select) and all the values are stored in the select all right. but the values are still not inserted.

Comment: yeah it returns nothing

Comment: It hits the `else` block and returns nothing?

Comment: no its not . the code runs alright, there's no error. its just my table in the database that is not being updated.

Comment: Also nothing being outputted is a definitive sign of an issue. You should at least see `Error: ` or you are in the `foreach`.